# Prove the existence of a natural number divisible by $q=2p+1$, where $q,p$ are primes, such that the sum of the digits is at most $3$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Prove the existence of a natural number divisible by $q=2p+1$, where $q,p$ are primes, such that the sum of the digits is at most $3$.

The digit sum is supposed to be equal to or less than $3$ in the decimal system. I thought about using the formula for digit sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{| \log_{10} x |} 10^{-2} (x \bmod 10^{n+1} - x \bmod 10^n)$$ and then expressing the appropriate variables but I can't get any further than that. Is this even the right way to go?

Comment: $3 \cdot 7 = 21?$ there are not that many small numbers whose digit sum is $3$.

Comment: You're looking for $a,b,c$ such that $10^a+10^b+10^c\equiv0\pmod q$.  TBH, I'm surprised it would take a sum of 3 and qualifiers on $q$.

Comment: Any natural number ending in $0$ and having any number of zeros, and having $3$ or fewer ones, or having only one $1$ and one $2$, is divisible by $10$. The sum of the digits in the number will be $3$ or less, and $10=2\cdot 5$, where $5=2(2)+1$

Comment: I think you are supposed to prove the existence of such a natural number regardless of the choice of p, i.e. for all p.